# How to select all child nodes from a parent node from xml if there are many parents node with same name?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<invoice>
        <obs>
        <ob>
         <code>ABC</code>
        </ob>
        <ob>
         <code>123</code>
        </ob>
        </obs>
      </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <obs>
        <ob>
         <code>DEF</code>
        </ob>
        </obs>
      </invoice>
    </invoices>
```

**Question:**
I have that xml, which will come to me from external system ,it can have large number of `invoice` nodes and one `invoice` node can have large number of 'code' nodes. I want to read the `code` nodes of all 'invoice' nodes and save them in an array like this :

```
invoice[1].code[1]=ABC 
invoice[1].code[2]=123 
invoice[2].code[1]=DEF
```

How to do this using XPathExpression in JAVA. My code is below which is not working.

```
expr = xpath.compile("//invoices/invoice/obs/ob/code/text()");

 result1=expr.evaluate(dc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

nodes =(NodeList)result1;
```

Please give some general solution in case of number of nodes are high.

Comment: There are 2 nodes where your xpath passes, if you want only one node you can get it from nodes. `nodes.item(0);`

Comment: please see the question again , i have made some changes

Answer (score 0):

It will give both as there are two invoices try to give id to your xml like

```html
<invoices>
  <invoice name="invoice1">
    <obs>
    <ob>
     <code>ABC</code>
    </ob>
    </obs>
  </invoice>
<invoice name="invoice2">
    <obs>
    <ob>
     <code>DEF</code>
    </ob>
    </obs>
  </invoice>
</invoices>
```

then

```html
expr = xpath.compile("//invoices[@name='invoice1']/invoice/obs/ob/code/text()");
```

Comment: I cant change the xml .Is there any way to count the no. of 'ob' nodes in a particular 'inovice' node?

Comment: I really don't know check whether this is working or not                count(//invoices/invoice/obs/ob)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 nodes where your xpath passes. You can try this.

```
    String xml = "<invoices><invoice><obs><ob><code>ABC</code></ob><ob><code>111</code></ob></obs></invoice><invoice><obs><ob><code>DEF</code></ob></obs></invoice></invoices>";
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder =factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document  = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

    Map<String,List<String>> invoiceCodeMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    XPathExpression invoiceXpathExp = xpathFactory.newXPath().compile("//invoices/invoice");
    NodeList invoiceNodes = (NodeList) invoiceXpathExp.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    //Iterate Invoice nodes
    for(int invoiceIndex=0;invoiceIndex<invoiceNodes.getLength();invoiceIndex++){
        String invoiceID = "invoice"+(invoiceIndex+1);
        List<String> codeList = new ArrayList<>();
        XPathExpression codeXpathExp = xpathFactory.newXPath().compile("obs/ob/code/text()");
        NodeList codeNodes = (NodeList) codeXpathExp.evaluate(invoiceNodes.item(invoiceIndex), XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for(int codeIndex=0;codeIndex<codeNodes.getLength();codeIndex++){
            Node code = codeNodes.item(codeIndex);
            codeList.add(code.getTextContent());
        }
        invoiceCodeMap.put(invoiceID, codeList);
    }
    System.out.println(invoiceCodeMap);
```

Comment: but it will not work in my case . I dont know what are the values in my xml. so i cant compare.

Comment: You said, I want to read all the 'code' nodes inside particular 'invoice' node
`NodeList codeNodes = (NodeList) xpathExp.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);` this will give all code nodes, and you said,  I want to read the node 'code' which value is 'ABC' `if(code.getTextContent().equals("ABC"))` this will do the trick. Explain your doubt clearly with some more text maybe that will help to provide good answer.

Comment: Ok , my question is , I have that xml , which will come to me from external system ,it can have large number of 'invoice' nodes and one 'invoice' node can have large number of  'code' nodes. I want to read the 'code' nodes of all 'invoice' nodes and save them in  an array like this : 

invoice[1].code[1]=ABC
invoice[1].code[2]=123
invoice[2].code[1]=DEF

I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this xpath:

```
//invoices/invoice[descendant::code[.='ABC']]/obs/ob/code
```